# Firebase OSX simple login with email/pass oddity

Tags: objective-c, macos, firebase

I'm setting up a very basic OSX app for an existing firebase with SimpleLogin and email/password authentication.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {

  Firebase* ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://myapp.firebaseio.com"];
  FirebaseSimpleLogin* authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];

  [authClient loginWithEmail:@"myemail@mydomain.com" andPassword:@"mypassword"
       withCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {

           if (error != nil) {
               // There was an error logging in to this account
               NSLog(@"authClient login error: %@", error);
           } else {
               NSLog(@"Login success.");

           }
       }];
}
```

Login is successful, and I see the log output. However, "FAUser* user" is nil. How? Why?
Online search / existing SO questions haven't helped..

Any ideas?

**** UPDATE ****

Same code in iOS works as expected. Is this just an OSX issue?

**** UPDATE 2 ****

I compiled the source code from the Firebase/Objective-C Simple Login Service (which seems to only reference iOS) directly in my OSX project and found that there is a "duplicate item" error code when the login service tries to store Keychain data on OSX.

The source code after the keychain save operation then proceeds to return a null user. I believe there is a logic error here because the if statement evaluates to true whenever it is not a success code (skipping the special case for duplicate item):

```
if (status != noErr) {        
    user = nil;
}
else if (status == errSecDuplicateItem) {
    // TODO: log an error?
    user = nil;
}
```

Anyway, I am able to continue working by modifying this small chunk of code to fit my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you're right. It's an error with accessing Keychain.

To clear the error on your own machine, you can go to Keychain Access, search for 'firebase' in the upper right. You should get an item with the name `https://auth.firebase.com`. Click it. Check that it says `Firebase_<YOUR_FIREBASE_NAME>` for the `Account` field, and go ahead and delete it. The next time you spin up your app, you'll have to log in again.

This seems to show up when you try to hit the same keychain item many times at once. Accessing the keychain slowly multiple times seems to be fine, so unless someone is authenticating many of the same app on the same machine, you shouldn't get the error. (If you can hit it some other way, please share!)