# sendPasswordResetForEmail user is nil

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Logging in a user to FireBase via FirebaseSimpleLogin seems to return nil for the user parameter.

```
[authClient loginWithEmail:@"email@domain.com"
               andPassword:@"very secret"
       withCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {

        if (error != nil) {
            // There was an error logging in to this account
        } else {
            // We are now logged in
        }

        if ( user ) {
           NSLog(@"user was not nil);
        }
    }];
```

I did find another post regarding the same issue:

[Firebase OSX simple login with email/pass oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597394/firebase-osx-simple-login-with-email-pass-oddity)

Any suggestions as to how to capture the user object?

It's a Mac app, OS X 10.9 & Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: what is being returned in the error param?

Comment: error = nil and user = nil as well. To isolate the issue, I created a brand new project with almost no code other than what's necessary for Firebase along with the the above code and get the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase OSX simple login with email/pass oddity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597394/firebase-osx-simple-login-with-email-pass-oddity)

Comment: So, after clearing the keychain (based on the comment in the other referenced post) and not running the app for two days, an error is now being logged when the app is first run.   Error Domain=com.firebase Code=9999 "expired_token" UserInfo=0xXXXXXXXXXXX {NSLocalizedDescription=expired_token}